# Get the begin and end coordinates of city municipality

Tags: coordinate-system, data, coordinates, geolocation

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. I would like to have an idea of precise coverage (extend) for the `latitude/longitude` of the city of Porto, Portugal.

This is in connection with my research that I need to filter out geolocation data for the cities of Porto (Portugal) and Beijing (China). Luckily, I found one for Beijing city [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_Beijing#:%7E:text=Beijing%20is%20a%20municipality%20located,to%20the%20east%20and%20south.)  as *"ranges from 39° 27' to 41° 03' N and in longitude from 115° 25' to 117° 30' E"* which is what I want.

For the city of Porto, all I get is a one-point coordinates (41.1579° N, 8.6291° W).

Any pointer to some resources?

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: It is unclear whether you want a bounding box (as implied by the Wikipedia page referenced) which is inexact, or the exact coverage as a polygon.

Comment: @nmtoken I am looking for coordinates of a bounding box, preferably covering the city municipality.

Answer (score 4):

changeset data from osm data for [administrative municipality of porto](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3372453) shows [min_lat="41.1383507" min_lon="-8.6912941" max_lat="41.1859353" max_lon="-8.5520090"](https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/changeset/72973759). the changeset bounding box covers the area shown in the relation.